# How to create a PDF with Python "appending" a HTML file and information from a database?

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I want to automate some report creation. Some elements that I need in the report are saved as rich text, so an HTML file. There are a couple of libraries to do this, such as html2pdf or pdfforge. However, I would also like to add extra information to the report that is not located in this HTML file, like for example a title or some information queried from the DB that is not necessarily in the HTML file.

Does anyone have a suggestion to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: create code which add data to HTML and then use other program to convert HTML to PDF